# DatePicker pre-set multiple dates

Tags: sapui5

I tried using `sap.m.DatePicker` to pre-select multiple date but without success.

Is there a way to pre-select few dates using the `sap.m.DatePicker`?

Comment: I guess this could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047896/bind-selecteddates-aggregation-for-calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is a date picker control and not dates picker control. I do not see how you can pre select multiple dates.

thanks
-D

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I finally used the sap.ui.unified.Calendar and the selectedDates aggregation. Maybe it will help someone.