# Bind selectedDates Aggregation for Calendar

Tags: sapui5

I tried to bind an array of dates to [sap.ui.unified.Calendar](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.Calendar) but without success. I am sure I am not far from the solution.

Here is the code:

```
var oCal = new sap.ui.unified.Calendar();
var oModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel([
    {myDate: new Date("2018-01-10"), tt:""},
    {myDate: new Date("2018-01-11"), tt:""},
    {myDate: new Date("2018-01-12"), tt:""},
]);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "MyData3");
var oItemTemplate = new sap.ui.unified.DateRange({
    startDate: "{MyData3>myDate}",
    endDate: "{MyData3>myDate}"
});     
oCal.bindAggregation("selectedDates", "MyData3>/", oItemTemplate);
```

I don't get any exception. The model has the data filled with 3 objects of type Date but I do not have those 3 dates pre-selected in the calendar.

If I fill the `selectedDates` aggregation manually (without binding) it will select those 3 dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working minimal example:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/unified/Calendar",
  "sap/ui/unified/DateRange",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
], (Calendar, DateRange, JSONModel) => new Calendar({
  singleSelection: false
}).bindAggregation("selectedDates", {
  path: "MyData3>/",
  template: new DateRange({
    startDate: "{MyData3>myDate}",
    endDate: "{MyData3>myDate}",
  }),
}).setModel(new JSONModel([
  {myDate: new Date("2018-01-10")},
  {myDate: new Date("2018-01-11")},
  {myDate: new Date("2018-01-13")},
]), "MyData3").placeAt("content")));
```

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-preload="async"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
  data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
></script><body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

I assume the provided code in your question is not a real excerpt from your project. Otherwise, you'd have got a ReferenceError saying that the variable `oModel` is undefined (instead, `oModel2` is defined). Apart from this, the actual reason why the binding did not work must be because the model is set on the core while the Calendar control is a descendant of [ComponentContainer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer). In that case, the Core model won't be propagated to the Component.

--> [Avoid setting models on the Core if the app is component-based.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251431/5846045)

---

If not already done: In order to display multiple selected dates in the first place, the Calendar property [`singleSelection`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.Calendar/methods/setSingleSelection) has to be disabled explicitly since it's enabled by default.

Comment: Hi, Great! It is working. I did not know that the Calendar has its own setModel method. Why is there a difference between the core Model and the Calendar Model ? Thanks again.

Comment: @user3462883 All modules including [Calendar](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.Calendar), which are extended from the [ManagedObject](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/setModel), offer the API `set` / `getModel` implicitly. Calling such APIs from a high-level module such as Calendar are just delegated to the ManagedObject prototype.